# How to move controls from the bottom to the top of an MFC form?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

In VC++ 6.0 (MFC), how the the controls eg : Button, EditBox, and Static Text can be move from bottom of the form to top of the form.

Answer (score 5):

You can use CWnd::MoveWindow() to move controls. CWnd::GetDlgItem() will retrieve a CWnd for a given control id.

Some pseudocode to be called from inside the class of the window that is parent of the controls:

```
RECT windowRect;
GetClientRect( &windowRect );// Bounds of the current window

CWnd* controlWindow = GetDlgItem( controlId );
RECT controlRect;
controlWindow->GetWindowRect( &controlRect );//control rectangle
ScreenToClient( &controlRect );//control rectangle in the coordinate system of the parent

const int vertOffset = windowRect.top - controlRect.top;//how much to adjust
controlRect.top += vertOffset;
controlRect.bottom += vertOffset;
controlWindow->MoveWindow( &controlRect );
```

Comment: can you show the sample of the code or any example, that i will get more clear.

Comment: I think there is a small mistake: It should be `controlRect.top = 0;` and `controlRect.bottom -= controlRect.top;` to move the control to the top of the parent window. I guess the code in the answer `vertOffset = windowRect.top - controlRect.top;` supposed that `controlRect` is relative to (the upper-left corner of) the screen, but it was already converted to client coordinate by `ScreenToClient`.